# The Old SKU can not change on the admin drid

Tags: magento-1.7

I have problem with the SKU's changing. Pls help me...
I try to modify the sku's at older products, but after saving the sku's does not changing... in the database is ok but on the admin panel I can see the old sku. At new added products no problem....
Thank you for your help

Comment: check by reindex and clear cache.

Comment: thank you for your answer...i tried but not helped...on the admmin grid is changed the sku but if i open to edit the product page i can see the old sku....

Comment: It sounds like some weird local caching issue. If the value is correct in the database but is still showing the old sku in the admin then it has to be getting pulled from somewhere. Have you tried completely flushing your local cache?

Comment: i flushed but no success...but i think the problem is not from caching because if i modify any other things like description or price, etc no problem....only at sku...